# Lift POST REST request on Lift always ends in 404

Tags: scala, http, rest, lift

I need to send JSON to Lift using a POST request, but all of my attempts for a POST request end in a 404 response. Right now, I'm trying to just send the JSON to Lift and echo it back. Here's my current code (it's gone through may iterations. I've been at this for some time):

```
object UpdateLibrary extends RestHelper {
  serveJxa {
    case "testGET" :: _ JsonGet _ => JString("Works!")
    case "testPOST" :: Nil JsonPost _ -> postData => new JsonResponse(postData.toString, Nil, Nil, 200)
  }
}
```

I try to connect to `http://localhost:8080/testPOST` with the Chrome extension PostMan using a POST request and I always get a 404. The GET request at `http://localhost:8080/testGET/call.json` works fine. Again, I've tried many variations for the POST line, but I can't much documentation for this and I'm really baffled by this part of the source code. I suppose I don't understand enough about the internals of how Lift handles requests to really make sense of that part of the source.

An older attempt at the POST serve line was:

```
case "testPOST" :: Nil JsonPost json -> _ => new JsonResponse(json, Nil, Nil, 200)
```

Or even:

```
case "testPOST" :: _ JsonPost _ -> json => JString("It works too!")
```

Obviously, there's a lot of guesswork going on here. How can I at least no longer have a 404 response?

Answer (score 0):

I had not specified the `content-type: application/json` header in my test. So the test was flawed, not the result.